# Convert multiple rows to one row with this code in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, case

my table is:

```
id   val     catid
 1   title1     7
 2   text1      8
 3   title2     7
 4   text2      8
```

I want combine rows as this:

```
val1     val2
title1     text1
title2     text2
```

I used this query:

```
select
 (case when catid = 7 then val end) val1,
 (case when catid = 8 then val end) val2
from mytable
```

But my result is:

```
val1     val2
title1     Null
Null       text1
title1     Null
Null       text2
```

How to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Look into pivot and unpivot.  Which DBMS?

Comment: pivot and unpivot not supported in sqlite. thanks @Tom

Comment: best to include that you're using SQLite :)

Comment: What decides that title1 and text1 should be in the same row?

Comment: execuse me @jpw. talk you later. please bookmark this url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `GROUP_CONCAT` function. Maybe you can use it in your program logic by splitting it by commas.

```
 select group_concat(val) as vals
 from table group by catid
```

In your app:

```
splitted_array = vals.Split(",");
key=splitted_array [0];
value=splitted_array [1];
```